# Confused, where is onCreateView method in MainActivity?

Tags: java, android

i followed online tutorial on how to create android app.
i want to assign variable in onCreateView, but where is the method?
im using androidstudio latest btw.
please help

Comment: An Activity is a View container, not a View itself. This is why you find tht method it in a Fragment, not in an Activity.

Comment: @BobMalooga Activity  is not a view container, neither Fragment is. And regular Views does not have `onCreateView()`.

Comment: If you would have  searched over Google.com instead of posting it here,You might got your answer without down vote.

Answer (score 3):

onCreateView is the method of a Fragment, rathen than an Activity.

As shown in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html):

> onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the **fragment**.

Comment: but in the tutorial, the onCreateView is in MainActivity.java, why is that?

Comment: Maybe the used inner class.

Comment: Search for `class PlaceholderFragment` in the `MainActivity`. I think `onCreateView` is method of a inner class named `PlaceholderFragment`.

Answer (score 3):

For an Activity the sort of equivalent method is `onCreate()`. You can override `onCreateView()` in a Fragment.

Comment: but in the tutorial, the onCreateView is in MainActivity.java, why is that?

Comment: There is an oncreateViewMethod for activities but it is part of the support library to enable v11 APIs on Honeycomb. You shouldn't use this anymore today.

Comment: what..?? ooo i see

Comment: Maybe they used a inner class Fragment? Either way you can't call onCreateView from your activity. Either use onCreate() or use it in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

> Confused, where is onCreateView method in MainActivity?

Nowhere. Activity does not have this method (it's Fragment's). Use `onCreate()` instead.

[image]

Comment: Looks like inner Fragment class. Not a good practice, so beware as this tutorial may teach you wrong things.

Answer (score 0):

create methods in activity is

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
```

create method in Fragment is

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```